# Validate JSON String using REGEX in JSONAssert java

Tags: java, json, jsonassert

I am storing my expected json string in the json file under resources as shown below. The json string consists of regular expression. I am using JSONAssert Library to compare two json strings.

```
{
  "timestamp": "^\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}T\\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}.\\d{3}+\\d{4}$",
  "status": 415,
  "error": "Unsupported Media Type",
  "message": "Content type 'text/plain;charset=ISO-8859-1' not supported",
  "path": "/service/addUser"
}
```

My actual response consists of timestamp in this format `2018-11-13T04:10:11.233+0000`

```
    JSONAssert.assertEquals(getJsonBody(expected), response.asString(),false);
```

Is always giving the below error on the regular expression

```
java.lang.AssertionError: timestamp
 Expected: ^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}.\d{3}+\d{4}$
      got: 2018-11-13T04:12:55.923+0000
```

Any recommendation on this error?

Comment: instead of comparing values, you should do something like `assertTrue(response.asString().matches(expected))`

Comment: Your regular expression is incorrect - dot and plus have special meaning and must be escaped. Try `^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d{3}\+\d{4}$`

Comment: I did escaped but it doesn't work. Same error

Comment: I have added this regex `[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}T[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}\\.[0-9]{3}\\+[0-9]{4}` but didnt worked

Comment: @Kartik I got some pattern matcher exception. Let me fix that

Comment: @vkrams ah, sorry, I misunderstood your question, let me update my answer

Comment: @kartik, your answer works. Thank you :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are comparing the pattern with the timestamp string. What you actually need to do is check if the timestamp **matches** the pattern.

Try this code:-

```
String expected = "{\n" +
        "  \"timestamp\": \"^\\\\d{4}-\\\\d{2}-\\\\d{2}T\\\\d{2}:\\\\d{2}:\\\\d{2}\\\\.\\\\d{3}\\\\+\\\\d{4}$\",\n" +
        "  \"status\": 415,\n" +
        "  \"error\": \"Unsupported Media Type\",\n" +
        "  \"message\": \"Content type 'text/plain;charset=ISO-8859-1' not supported\",\n" +
        "  \"path\": \"/service/addUser\"\n" +
        "}";
String actual = "{\n" +
        "  \"timestamp\": \"2018-11-13T04:12:55.923+0000\",\n" +
        "  \"status\": 415,\n" +
        "  \"error\": \"Unsupported Media Type\",\n" +
        "  \"message\": \"Content type 'text/plain;charset=ISO-8859-1' not supported\",\n" +
        "  \"path\": \"/service/addUser\"\n" +
        "}";
JSONAssert.assertEquals(
        expected,
        actual,
        new CustomComparator(
                JSONCompareMode.LENIENT,
                new Customization("***", new RegularExpressionValueMatcher<>())
        )
);
```

So with your code, it will look something like:-

```
JSONAssert.assertEquals(
        getJsonBody(expected),
        response.asString(),
        new CustomComparator(
                JSONCompareMode.LENIENT,
                new Customization("***", new RegularExpressionValueMatcher<>())
        )
);
```